# MMB deletes in edit mode instead of orbiting

Tags: edit-mode

This has happened twice recently where I am editing a model and (perhaps sloppily hitting a key that activates this "feature") and the middle mouse button no longer orbits but deletes anything selected.

This doesn't happen in object mode or anywhere else, just in edit mode. To clarify, in edit mode the mmb does not orbit at all - just deletes any vertices I have selected, if any.

Does anyone know what's going on here? What "feature" might I have activated with my sloppy hands and how can I stop this behavior?

also, resetting to default preferences solved this issue, which is why I'm assuming this is due to an accidental key press activating some mode that I don't know how to reverse. I just don't want to keep resetting my preferences on this file...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: also, resetting to default preferences solved this issue, which is why I'm assuming this is due to an accidental key press activating some mode that I don't know how to reverse. I just don't want to keep resetting my preferences on this file...

Comment: Hi and welcome :) Please add all new information as an [edit] to your question text rather than as comments. There are many users that do not read comments, and comments are not searchable. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip!